# Creating Singleton with Public Init Parameters

Tags: swift, constructor, singleton

I'm trying to create a singleton, but the Class 'IAPHelper' it's instantiating has a public init method that takes a parameter.

I can't see how to pass the required parameter, so I get the error message:

"Cannot use instance member 'productIdentifiers' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

```
open class IAPHelper: NSObject  {

   private let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
   private var purchasedProductIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = []
   private var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
   private var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

   static let shared = IAPHelper(productIds: productIdentifiers)  

   public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
       productIdentifiers = productIds
       for productIdentifier in productIds {
           let purchased = KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
           if purchased ?? false {
               purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
               print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
           } else {
               print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
           }
       }
       super.init()

       SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't inject values into a singleton initialiser. Are you sure you need a singleton in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to create an addTransactionObserver call in AppDelegate. I thought that since only one payment transaction queue should ever be running, then I should ensure only one instance of IAPHelper is created by using a singleton. I've been trying to follow example code from Apple, in which the class the singleton is created from doesn't pass any parameters in it's initializer. However, mine has a public init that takes a parameter.